# What is the difference between JTAG and EJTAG

Tags: debugging, hardware, jtag

I want to know what is the difference between JTAG and EJTAG? I know about JTAG as Its a hardware tool used to examine the memory and registers. Correct me if i wrong.

Comment: this might be better asked on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Octopus Thanks i asked there